# How to create Mediafiles linking to webressources, so that the ressource will be streamed?

Tags: audio, video, video-streaming, mp3, avi

I want to create some honeydocs, therefore I would like to create some media files like .mp3, .mp4 or .avi etc. When a user opens the file a callback to my server should be established.

Is there a possiblity to link from one of the common media files to a webressource for streaming proposes which would create such a backcall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer:

one only needs to create a text-file with the content of the callback address like "http://example.com:443/tracking/DocumentID.mp3" for an mp3 file and .avi for an avi.

now one can rename the file exentsions to .avi or .m3u (for mp3 the according streaming file extension is .m3u).

- VCL media player will always make a call back
- Microsoft Groove makes no callback and outputs an error message
- Windows Media Player makes only a callback for .m3u